# Windows 10 Pro - Automatically Turn On Mobile Hotspot And Keep It On

Tags: windows-10, hotspot

My laptop connects to my WiFI without a problem but my phones can't seem to connect to it probably because of the range. I've set up a mobile hotspot on Windows 10 and I connect both phones to it. The problem is, any time my laptop disconnects and reconnects to the WiFi, the mobile hotspot doesn't turn back on.

I'd like the mobile hotspot to turn on automatically when the laptop is connected to an active WiFi network. I'd like to keep it on at all times, even if there is no activity on the connected devices.

Any app, script, or built-in setting change will do the trick. I'm not picky. I just need it to work.

Answer (score 0):

```ps
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass 
"$connectionProfile = [Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation,Windows.Networking.Connectivity,ContentType=WindowsRuntime]::GetInternetConnectionProfile(); 
$tetheringManager = [Windows.Networking.NetworkOperators.NetworkOperatorTetheringManager,Windows.Networking.NetworkOperators,ContentType=WindowsRuntime]::CreateFromConnectionProfile($connectionProfile); 
$tetheringManager.StartTetheringAsync();"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).